# Eclipse: Jasper Report Studio plugin: Not show Repository Explorer

Tags: eclipse, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Windows 10 (64 bit)
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2

I success install **Jaspersoft Studio** plugin
[image]

But after restart Eclispe it's not show **Repository Explorer**
[image]

Comment: Try to reset panels & clean caches

Comment: Not help. Same result